# Use C/C++ in Apache-Flink

Tags: c++, apache-flink

My team and I are developing an application that makes use of Flink.
The data will be processed using a computationally-heavy numerical algorithm.
In order to optimize it as much as possible, I would like to write this algorithm in C/C++ rather than in Java.

The question is: is it possible to use C/C++ code within Flink? Perhaps by wrapping it into a Java library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tested this case in particular. In general, you can always use native code from Java using [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), the Java Native Interface.

The idea would be to have a Java facade expose your native code and use these methods in your computation graph defined with Flink in Java (or other JVM languages, like Scala). You would have to make both Java and native libraries available on all involved nodes to make this work. If you have an Hadoop cluster you can leverage YARN to ship files along with your job (docs [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/apis/cli.html), see `--yarn-ship` CLI option).

I would suggest you test this incrementally, with a very small native function exposed. Also, don't underestimate Java's capabilities in terms of performance: with some well thought programming and leveraging JIT and other runtime optimizations, long running processes can enjoy even better performances than similar native code with unmanaged memory.

Keep in mind that this of course resorting to native code will mean restricting the portability of your code to the platforms for which you'll compile your libraries.